# Locus of the circumcentre of a variable triangle.

Tags: circles, locus

I have a question related to circle that "Given the circle with equation $x^2+y^2-2x-2y+1=0$. Tangents $PA$ and $PB$ are drawn from a point $P$ to the given circle.It is given that $P$ lies on the line $lx+my+n=0$, where $l$,$m$,$n$ are constants. Find the locus of the circumcentre of the triangle $PAB$."

My approach: We can take any point on the given line and easily find out the equation of chord of contact i.e $AB$ of tangents by the formula $T =0$. Now my question is how to proceed for the circumcentre. I know that circumcentre of a triangle is the point of intersection of perpendicular bisector of the sides of the triangle. Please provide any hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The locus is a straight line (dotted line in the figure below).

Let $C(1,1)$ be the center of the given circle. Let $E$, $F$ be the contact points of the tangents issued from $P$. Due to the symmetry with respect to line $PC$ of the two tangents, $PEF$ is an isosceles triangle; therefore, the center $G$ of the circumscribed circle, which is situated on the altitude issued from $P$ in triangle $PEF$ is aligned with $P$ and $C$.

Moreover, $G$ is the midpoint of segment PC for the following reason: radius $EC$ being orthogonal to tangent $PE$ in contact point $P$, $\widehat{PEC}$ is a right angle, thus $PC$ is a diameter of the circumscribed circle; therefore $G$ is the midpoint of $PC$.

The locus of such a midpoint is the homothetic line from the original line in the homothety $\frak{H}$$(C,1/2)$, thus a parallel line to the original line.

**Remark:** The equation of this line is necessarily of the form $\ell x + my +n_1=0$ because they share the same normal vector $(\ell,m)$ with the original line. It remains to find $n_1$. This can be done by using the distance formula from point $C$ to the two straight lines (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).

[image]

Comment: yeah got it. many many thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it is my pleasure. I have added a remark dealing with the equation of the locus.

Comment: Fine, new labels E,F for  A,B?

Comment: Yes, I have redefined them in my answer. I was in fact "prisoner" of the notations of the Geogebra figure I had done in a first step.

Comment: I couldn't get if the locus of circumcenter is midpoint of $PC$ how it turned out to be a straight line parallel to original line.i don't know about homothety.please explain

Comment: @user471651 Let us prove it without homothety. If $A$ has coord. $(x_0,y_0)$ and $M(x,y)$ belongs to the line with equation $\ell x + my = -p $ (equ. (1)), then G, being the midpoint of AM, has coordinates $x'=(x_0+x)/2,y'=(y_0+y)/2 \iff 2x'=x_0+x ; 2y'=y_0+y$ (equ. (2a) and (2b)). Taking the combination of equ.:  $\ell \times(2a) + m \times (2b)$ you get $2\ell x'+2 my'= (\ell x_0+ my_0)+(\ell x+ my) $ i.e., using (1) and dividing by 2: $\ell x'+ my'= (\ell x_0+ my_0)/2-p/2$ which is the equation of a straight line parallel to the initial line

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Let $C$ be the center of the given circle. Then the circumcircle of $PAB$ goes through $C$ and the triangles $\triangle PAC$ and  $\triangle PBC$ are right triangles. This implies that the centre of the circumcircle is the midpoint of the segment $PC$. If follows that the locus of these circumcircles is a straight line which is parallel to the given one.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

The given circle $C_1$ has unit radius and touches x-, y- coordinate axes at $(1,0),(0,1).$  Required variable circle center has diameter  $P C_1$ with tangent lengths $ PA= PB= P C_1$  and its cicumcenter center is on the bisector of tangents $ PA,PB $ as center point of $PC_1$. (Corrected)